# How to register global shortcut (accelerator) in electron

Tags: electron

Well I am very new to electron and Developing web apps. I am not good at reading docs. How to register **globalshort** cut for electron.

Comment: the question and your username *almost* make this feel like a satirical question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use globalshortcut module to detect keyboard events even when the application does not have keyboard focus. This should be used afer the app fires **'ready'** event.

```
const { app, globalShortcut } = require('electron')

app.on('ready', () => {
  globalShortcut.register('CommandOrControl+X', () => {
    console.log('CommandOrControl+X is pressed')
  })
})
```

As electron is used for cross platform so you have to use (CommandOrControl + key) not Command + key for mac or control + key for windows or linux.

If you want to be a good software developer you'll come across situations when you've to read docs and solve a particular problems.
So at least give it a try [docs](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/global-shortcut)